# Obsole warnings using AutoMapper version 4.2.1 and how to solve

Tags: automapper

According to the occurrence of questions about 'AutoMapper Migraton from static API' lately and the fact I was Exploring Christos Sakell blog 'Building Single Page Applications using Web API and AngularJS', I also came across some obsolete warnings.

/***********************************************************************************
 * AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap()' is obsolete: 'Dynamically creating maps will be removed in version 5.0. 
 * Use a MapperConfiguration instance and store statically as needed, or Mapper.Initialize. 
 * Use CreateMapper to create a mapper instance. 
 ***********************************************************************************/

Completely ignorant of recent changes of AutoMapper (I using this mapping tool for the very first time) I was trying to get rid of those obsolete messages. Searching around I came across two possible solutions:

1) http://quabr.com/36398318/automapper-mapper-createmaptsource-tdestination-is-obsolete , and

2) http://davecallan.com/automapper-4-2-example/#comment-8914

These hints seemed to be pretty straightforward. It turned out tweaking the *MappingProfile classes weren't that difficult, but what to do on several controllers? That was a complete different piece of cake. I got completely lost. I ran in all kind of strange errors not knowing or having a clue what to do. Even the just mentioned blogs weren’t that explanative. More or less, I got the feeling they were keeping the puzzle a live (I'm kidding).

So the question was: how to solve the troublesome mapping from the controller to the *MappingProfile class. Luckily, I found a possible solution, so please tackle it...

Answer (score 0):

I do like puzzling and buzzing around the net, I finally found a combination of hints, and that's what I want to share with you.

The solution for this is a combination of tweaks.

First of all, have a look at page 'Migrating from static API' (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API).

Notice the second block right below ‘In 4.2.x and later …’ that’s what is needed on several controllers. Dave Callan just gave a part of the clue. He just forgot a part of the solution. So I asked him to add the missing part to his solution as well.

So, implementing the hint on the 'Migrating from static API' page in combination with the suggestion of Dave Callan (http://davecallan.com/automapper-4-2-example/#comment-8919) block 1: Instantiating a new MapperConfiguration(...) in *MappingProfile class(es), you can get rid of those obsolete warnings: On every cycle proper mapping. 
At least, I got rid of those warnings.

What will happend in the nearer future with AutoMapper, hopefully those guys in Austin TX will make proper decisions on this matter.

I also testing the code (block 2 of 'Migration from static API') with the suggestion on Quabr (instead of instantiating a new MapperConfiguration, they suggest to call the Initialize  method of the current Mapper). This combination gave my errors like ‘index outside matrix borders’.

Apparently on each cycle the mapping lists are not renewed. This combination of code tweaks resulted (to me) in a ‘no go’. Perhaps others, do not agree with me, fine, at least that’s what I noticed.

My only goal is to help other members who are facing comparable trouble. 
I'm pleased to share my solution. Have fun